# Expression to match strings starting with string, but not containing some other string?

Tags: regex

How do I construct an expression that matches these:

```
start?foo=bar
start.php
starter
```

But not these

```
dontmatch
start?foo=dontmatch
notstart?foo=bar
```

I intend to use it in an .htaccess file.

Comment: start?foo=dontmatch is same as start?foo=bar

Answer (score 0):

How about this expression:

```
\bstart.*$(?<!dontmatch)
```

**[Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rJ4hV3/1)**

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?!.*dontmatch)start
```

matches if

- the text `start` is found
- at the start of a line (that's what the `^` [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) is there for, assuming the regex is run in multiline mode),
- unless the text `dontmatch` occurs anywhere on the same line (that's what the `(?!...)` [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) is there for).

The match will consist only of the text `start` - if you want the entire line to be returned, add a `.*` at the end.